# Firebase Recycler Adapter

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

Hi in my Firebase recycler adapter, in my fourth parameter I require a database reference however I would like to reference  one child, and from the UID in that child and then reference another. Like in the screenshot below: I am trying to reference the key from "Chatmessages", and then use that to reference the keys in "Users". However how can i do this in my Recycler Adapter?

[DB struc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/beE3P.jpg)

```
public void loadUserList() {
    FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<User, UserViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<User, UserViewHolder>(
            User.class,
            R.layout.userlist_layout,
            UserViewHolder.class,

            users // ref
    )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [FirebaseIndexRecyclerAdapter](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/database/src/main/java/com/firebase/ui/database/FirebaseIndexRecyclerAdapter.java) from Firebase-UI:

```
public void loadUserList() {
    String chatMessageId = "5kA...LT2";    // Get or pass this key somehow
    DatabaseReference userKeyRef = rootRef.child("Chatmessages").child(chatMessageId);
    DatabaseReference userRef = rootRef.child("Users");
    FirebaseIndexRecyclerAdapter<User, UserViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseIndexRecyclerAdapter<User, UserViewHolder>(
            User.class,
            R.layout.userlist_layout,
            UserViewHolder.class,
            userKeyRef,
            userRef
    )
```